# Sublime Text 4 sql highlight inside a string

Tags: syntax-highlighting, python3, string-manipulation

Currently, if I have sql commands inside a python string, Sublime Text highlights it. However if it's an "f string", it does not recognize the sql inside. Is there any way to make it work the same way as a regular string?

[image: example of sql highlight]

Comment: Did you ever find solution to this? I have the same problem in 2023...  Using Sublime4 build 4143

Comment: @ArtGertner Unfortunately no, I haven't look for it though. I'll see if I find something